# How to reorder xml tags from marshal

Tags: xml, go

The program I'm exporting XML for seems to want the xml tags to be in a specific order like the example below

```
<xml>
  <tagType1>data 1</tagType1>
  <tagType2>data 2</tagType2>
  <tagType1>data 3</tagType1>
  <tagType2>data 4</tagType2>
</xml>
```

In go, I marshal into a struct like below

```
type xml struct {
  TagType1 []string `xml:"tagType1"`
  TagType2 []string `xml:"tagType2"`
}
```

When I marshal that back out, it sorts the tags which is expected, but that is not what I need.

```
<xml>
  <tagType1>data 1</tagType1>
  <tagType1>data 3</tagType1>
  <tagType2>data 2</tagType2>
  <tagType2>data 4</tagType2>
</xml>
```

Is there a way with the encoding/xml package to reproduce the output in the first example? The order varies. I read an xml file with specific orders, modify the data and marshal that back out. I need the tag order to be kept.

Comment: You could use individual fields for each child element. `encoding/xml` marshals fields in the order they appear in the struct definition (which is the behavior you're seeing now).

Comment: The amount and order of the child elements varies with each parent element. I need each tag to be a slice or be able to expand the amount of child elements depending on how many there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use something like this:

```
type xml struct {
   Item []ItemStruct `xml:",any"`
}

type ItemStruct struct {
  XMLName xml.Name
  Value string `xml:",chardata"`
}
```

That way you can keep the order, but you need to get the element name from each item by `Item[i].XMLName`